# How can I take an integer input from user and store it to an array?

Tags: python, arrays

How can I take an integer input from the user and store it to an array? and once stored print it. Iv tried to do it this way but I get the error:

> 'number' not defined

My code:

```
number = []

if __name__=="__main__":
x = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))
number.append(x)
print number
```

Comment: The code you posted should work (assuming the indentation is a copy&paster error). What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: -1 for not posting the real code but an example that does not have whatever issue your real code has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last line to:
print str(number)

This will change the list into a printable string representation.

If you want to learn more about strings and formatting, check out Chapter 7 of the Python Tutorial.  Actually, the whole tutorial is pretty awesome. :)

EDIT:  David is correct in his comment below...print converts lists to strings automatically (I suppose it does so for any type with a defined string conversion).  I'm still a noob too. :p

Anyway, I just checked your code in the Python interpreter, and it worked (as Lukáš Lalinský said it should).  Have you checked your indentation?  Also, if you happen to be using Python3, you'll need to turn print into a function, e.g.:
print(number)

Comment: print automatically invokes the objects `__str__` method which is the same as calling `str(x)` manually. It's much more likely an indentation error, or perhaps he should've added a `global` declaration for `number`

Comment: Thanks.  I get the feeling it's indentation too, unless he's using Python 3.  Would a global declaration matter in this case though?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have a letter case error in the real code. You define Number but print number, or vice versa. Names in Python are case sensitive.

Or perhaps you have code in a function which tries to access number which was declared outside the function.

Without seeing your actual code it's hard to say and we have to guess!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what error you are receiving as this is valid Python 2.x, but if you happen to be using the less used 3.x, some of the code examples you may have looked at in regards to `print` would be incorrect. In Python version 3+, `print` is no longer a special statement and is instead a function. Therefore, if this is the case, you should be doing `print(number)` instead of `print number`.

Comment: But Python 3 would give a different error I think.

Comment: True, I did not notice the error description in the question. What I referenced would have resulted in a syntax error.